# ¿Agregar el cuadro de confirmación con contraseña en PHP antes de eliminar?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una tabla en mi php que muestra los datos de una tabla en mi base de datos: nombre de usuario, correo, etc. y también he agregado una opción de eliminar. La opción de eliminar funciona correctamente y muestra un mensaje de confirmación antes de eliminar. Sin embargo, quiero agregar un mensaje de confirmación con una contraseña necesaria cuando el usuario haga clic en la opción de eliminar.

Cada vez que presiono la opción de eliminar, aparece un mensaje de confirmación para eliminar los datos que quiero, sin embargo, me gustaría que el mensaje de confirmación tenga una contraseña para eliminar completamente el mensaje. Me gustaría que muestre un mensaje tipo: `confirm ('Ingrese la contraseña para poder eliminar') ;`.

¿Alguien sabe cómo se puede hacer? Gracias.

Esto es lo que tengo hecho:

index.php:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3"><h2>Users</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Name </th>
        <th> Email </th>
        <th> Delete</th>
    </tr>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows==0){

    echo "No users";
}else{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["username"]."</td><td>".$row["email"]."</td><td><a class='eliminate' onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm deletion');\" href=\"delete.php?id=".$row['id']."\">X</a></td></tr>";
    }
}

?>
</table>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
include('Conexion.php');// Check connection with DB
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$id = $_GET['id']; // $id is defined

mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM users WHERE id='".$id."'");
mysqli_close($conn);
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

He pensado en hacer un script como este:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  var password = prompt("Please confirm deletion and enter the password to delete:", "Password");
  if (password == null || password == "" || password != "realpassword") {
    txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
  } else {
    txt = "Are you sure?";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
```

Comment: No puedes hacer eso en Javascript. Si el usuario explora el contenido de la página verá cuál es la contraseña `realpassword`.  Debes entender que el código Javascript **está del lado del cliente**, por tanto, un usuario más o menos habilidoso puede explorar con facilidad ese contenido. Tendrías que hacerlo a nivel de servidor, antes de ejecutar la consulta `DELETE`, verificar mediante una variable si es o no la clave correcta. Para más seguridad puedes usar un hash o algo así.

Comment: @A.Cedano podría guardar la contraseña en otro fichero o incluso en la base de datos? para no facilitar la contraseña

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo con @A.Cedano, la confirmación en javascript vale para evitar *falsos positivos* (pulsaciones del usuario por error) pero el tema de seguridad debe ir en el servidor: haz una pagina intermedia donde se pida la contraseña o pídela ahí y borra por ajax, pero lo que no puedes es manejar información confidencial en javascript.

Comment: Hay varios lugares donde puedes guardar la contraseña. Quizá lo más seguro sea en una tabla de la base de datos, donde la puedes guardar de forma encriptada aumentando la seguridad. A esa tabla le restringirías el acceso para que otros usuarios de la BD con privilegios menores no puedan leer / modificar sus datos si fuera el caso.